# IDEA error "Managed bean must be a concrete class, or is annotated with @Decorator"

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, abstract-class, cdi

In my Java EE project I have a few abstract classes. IntelliJ IDEA underlines them red and tells me:

> **Managed bean must be a concrete class, or is annotated with @Decorator**
>
> A top-level Java class is a managed bean if it is defined to be a managed bean by any other Java EE specification, or if it meets all of the following conditions:
>
> - It is not a non-static inner class.
> - It is a concrete class, or is annotated @Decorator.
> - It is not annotated with an EJB component-defining annotation or declared as an EJB bean class in ejb-jar.xml.
> - It has an appropriate constructor—either:
>
>   - the class has a constructor with no parameters, or
>   - the class declares a constructor annotated @Inject.

I just want to use abstract classes, without any annotation. Although IntelliJ shows me that this is an error my JBoss server doesn't complain about it.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 6):

My guess is this is the Managed Bean Inconsistency errors inspection in Settings > Editor > Inspections > CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection). Its severity is Error, so it will be underlined with a red squiggly line.

It seems you don't really care for this inspection, so just deselect it and save your changes.

Comment: That solves it! But what if one doesn't want to ignore this problem but fix it? How to solve this issue about Managed Beans?